# Running Selenium Webdriver Test on Android Mobile Emulator

Tags: java, android, selenium, android-emulator, appium

I'm trying to run WebDriver test on a mobile emulator but it doesn't seem to be working.
So this is quick run down of my setup:

1. I write my test in Java using Eclipse
2. I'm using WebDriver with TestNG framework
3. I'm using Appium and I already have Android SDK downloaded
4. I have installed android server and android WebDriver on my emulator

I'm setting up Appium like this

```
   File appDir = new File("C:/Appium");
   File app = new File(appDir, "android-server-2.38.0.apk");
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Android Emulator");
   capabilities.setCapability("browsername",  "safari");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

Every time I run the test I see a black screen on the emulator and all it says is 'WebDriver Ready' then this black screen close and on my console it says 'Not yet implemented'

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37'
System info: host: 'C025', ip: '169.254.167.218', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Session ID: d72cf56d-8364-4353-92a4-817c377a60b2
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platformVersion=4.4, app=C:\Appium\android-server-2.38.0.apk, platform=LINUX, databaseEnabled=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browsername=safari, platformName=Android, deviceName=Android Emulator, browserName=Android, webStorageEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={platformVersion=4.4, app=C:\Appium\android-server-2.38.0.apk, browsername=safari, deviceName=Android Emulator, platformName=Android}, locationContextEnabled=false, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:304)
    at RegisterUser.setUp(RegisterUser.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me to figure this out.  I'm not new to WebDriver but I'm new to mobile testing.

Full structure of class...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class RegisterUser {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod()
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

    }

    @Test()
    public void registerNewUser() throws Exception {        

    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {       

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the body of your setUp() method?

Comment: DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Nexus_4");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
capabilities.setCapability("browsername",  "Browser");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:/Appium/android-server-2.38.0.apk");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
driver.get("https://whateverwebsiteiwanttotest"); 
driver.manage().window().maximize(); }

Comment: As you can see I've modified it slightly by trying to match it to the output in the Appium window but still no luck.

Comment: Please edit your original post! Code in comments is very hard to read.

Comment: So far, your code looks reasonable. Go through the suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and see if you can narrow things down.

Comment: which versions of java-client and selenium-java are you using ...

Use java-client LATEST and selenium 2.42.2 and use AndroidDriver() instead of RemoteWebDriver().

Comment: Ram, I'm using java 7.0.510 and selenium 2.42.2.  Thanks for your suggestion I'll give them a try